# Add window.navigator.standalone to UIWebView DOM

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, web-applications, ios

You know how a "webapp" can be installed via Mobile Safari by tapping the + button?
And by launching this app via the homescreen your webapp knows that it was launched from the homescreen because `window.navigator.standalone` is set to 1...

Well..

I made an iOS app with a `UIWebView` that loads a web app. And now I'd like to add the `window.navigator.standalone` property to the dom of my webapp... is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject some Javascript into the webview from the objective C to set the parameter manually

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.navigator.standalone=1"];
```

-Dx

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, the value `window.navigator.standalone` remains `false` even after this execution.

Comment: iOS 6.1: code implemented on webViewDidFinishLoad: but same result. The value of `window.navigator.standalone` remains `false` :(

Comment: Did anyone ever find the answer to this?  It remains false no matter how it is set it seems.

Comment: @casey See my answer below.

Comment: Check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64965600/3290623 it shows how to override that flag

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. `navigator.standalone` is *read-only* like most native navigator properties. I just checked with an iPhone Emulator in Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Inject the following into your webview

```
let script= "Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'standalone', {get:function(){return true;}});"
evaluateJavaScript(script, completionHandler: nil)
```

That way you can even override read only objects